# Problem with Maven in POM Don't copy file

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have a problem with my ear in Maven, I find this error, but i don't find answer, please help

```
Error to compile in Maven Goals Clean Install

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:ear (default-ear) on project DashboardOSM-ear: Cannot copy a directory: C:\Users\Coneja\Desktop\OSM_DashboardBackend\OSM_DashboardBackend\commonModule\target\classes; Did you package/install DashboardOSMEar:commonModule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile? -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:ear (default-ear) on project DashboardOSM-ear: Cannot copy a directory: C:\Users\Coneja\Desktop\OSM_DashboardBackend\OSM_DashboardBackend\commonModule\target\classes; Did you package/install DashboardOSMEar:commonModule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile?
```

And the pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>DashboardOSMEar</groupId>
    <artifactId>DashboardOSM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>DashboardOSMEar</groupId>
  <artifactId>DashboardOSM-ear</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>


  <name>DashboardOSMEar</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <version>5</version>
          <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>DashboardOSMWar</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>commonModule</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>configurationModule</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>queryModule</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you sure you pom is sane? I don't think that a maven-clean-plugin should be valid dependency, and for the rest, the error could simply mean that some of your dependency were not compiled first. This might also help: https://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg142808.html

Comment: Thank's for your answer I'm noob in Maven, sorry if  you find some unusual. I compiled all the dependecy previuos, EAR is the only thing that does not compiles.  EAR not copy  a directory: C:\Users\Coneja\Desktop\OSM_DashboardBackend\OSM_DashboardBackend\commonModule\target\classes;                       and says this ->                                      
          Did you package/install DashboardOSMEar:commonModule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile? -> [Help 1]    I don't understand why question me if I installor package.

Comment: maven-clean-plugin is a maven plugin. It should not be there as dependency. Also, you should check that your parent module clearly reference all dependencies (the "reactor"), otherwise Maven can't build project in the good order and it may lead to errors (well, you may build those project manually first).